# Using computed value or trigger to update a row with data from a different row in the same table?

Tags: mysql, database

I wish to do an insert for `2019-08-15` for `mainKey = 1` and if the total is bigger than `200` on `2019-08-14` I want to save the difference in last column in the new row that was created for `2019-08-15`. The `total` is a value that can stay the same or increase.

```
+------------+---------+-------+--------------------------+
| date       | mainKey | total | differenceSinceYesterday |
+------------+---------+-------+--------------------------+
| 2019-08-14 |       1 |   200 |                        0 |
| 2019-08-14 |       2 |   500 |                        0 |
+------------+---------+-------+--------------------------+
```

`date` and `mainKey` together uniquely identify the row so a row for specific `mainKey` can only be inserted once a day.

```
+--------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| date                     | date    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| mainKey                  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| total                    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| differenceSinceYesterday | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I looked into triggers but if ran AFTER UPDATE it becomes recursive because it is the same table. Or should I transfer the logic to an external script that does inserts in the first place and run another `SELECT` to find 1 day old row with specific `mainKey` and update the today's row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, checking for a `total` value from the previous day of >= 200, and if it exists, setting the `differenceSinceYesterday` value to the difference between today's and yesterday's totals:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER updateDifference
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE yesterday INT;
  SELECT total INTO yesterday FROM table1 WHERE date = NEW.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND mainKey = NEW.mainKey;
  IF yesterday >= 200 THEN
     SET NEW.differenceSinceYesterday = NEW.total - yesterday;
  END IF;
END;
DELIMITER ;
INSERT INTO table1 (date, mainKey, total)
VALUES ('2019-08-15', 1, 400), ('2019-08-16', 1, 300);
SELECT * FROM table1
```

Output:

```
date                mainKey total   differenceSinceYesterday
2019-08-14 00:00:00 1       200     0
2019-08-14 00:00:00 2       500     0
2019-08-15 00:00:00 1       400     200
2019-08-16 00:00:00 1       300     -100
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rTDo1wyKneMyjwMTzEdJuq/0)

Comment: Thank you for an extensive answer. I was not aware of the `SELECT INTO Variable` concept.

Comment: One more question: I find the `BEFORE INSERT` non-intuitive because we are triggering an event here before the row is created and modifying said row. How to wrap head around this?

Comment: @miyagisan yes, you could use `SET yesterday = (SELECT ...)` as well, I find the `INTO` version a bit easier to read.

Comment: @miyagisan `BEFORE INSERT` triggers are intended for modifying the data you are about to insert based on other factors (in your case, yesterdays value of the same colum). `AFTER INSERT` triggers are intended for modifying other tables based on the inserted data, once you know the `INSERT` has succeeded.